# C# win forms datagrid view displaying MySql table

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Hi there i am trying to load MySql table data into a datagridview in my win forms application on button click, and cant seem to get it to work. I think im missing the binding source but im very confused.

Some help would be appreciated.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string connStr = "Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=bitdb;User Id=root;Password='';"; 
         string query = "Select * from Client"; 
         using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
         {
             using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
             {
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 adapter.Fill(ds);
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: What does the debugger say? Getting the table successful? Including some columns? Also, don't you need some column definitions on the datagridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you should use a `BindingSource` with the `DataGridView` component. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string connStr = "Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=bitdb;User Id=root;Password='';"; 
         string query = "Select * from Client"; 
         using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
         {
             using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
             {
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 adapter.Fill(ds);
                 var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
                 bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
             }
         }
     }
```

Also, any error information would be helpful.

Comment: thanks yer i was missing the binding the source iv got the data displaying now. Cheers again